# Not detects mesh as object?

Tags: mesh, objects

that's my first question here in blender stackexchange, so I'll try to be specific;

I have modelled a city with more than 30 objects, but my problem is that Blender not detects each mesh as object. I mean, when I select each "object", in the upper menu where displays the project info (verts, faces, ) says 0/2 objects. 
I don't know why shows me 0/2 objects instead of 0/30 objects. 
I've found 2 buildings that Blender detects as objects, but the rest of the models doesn't recognise them as objects.

**How can I "set" the other models as "blender objects"?** 
I need for exporting them to 3ds files, and Blender won't export anything if is not an object.

thanks!

[image: Here shows 0/2 objects when I have selected one]
[image: Here detects the only 2 objects from the scene]

(I restored a previous file where it detects 4 objects instead 2)
I have each kind of building in separate layers, but the object's number doesn't change if I change the layer where I'm working

[image: Fullscreen]

Comment: I think all the object are on different layers. The below 2 are in same layer so they show 2/2

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot showing expanded outliner, and 3d view header?

Comment: @atek I added screenshot to layers and outline. Yes, I have objects in different layers, but in other layers won't show 0/X objects, the object's number won't change.

Comment: can u attach your file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?ref=be-community-add-2

Comment: I've modified the question with the link to the blend-exchange, thanks!

Comment: I got the answer i will let u know in few min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select one of the object and click this button

[image]

Use the scene's active camera and layer in this view rather than local layer.

It has link in one scene into other scene

[image]

For more information please watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXSsyf8C-KY)

Comment: That was what I wanted... Thank you so much!!!